# how to append data using ajax posts and datatables are not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

[image]

Hello there am trying to get the data from database using ajax posts but i didn't get any data properly. first column data is splinting in another columns(Member names are coming in image field and info field). Image also shared please check that. And also datatables are not working while fetching the data using Ajax. Help me out from this problem...

Thanks & Regards

```
<body>
      <label>Party</label>  
      <select id='partydropdown' name='partydropdown' onchange="partyFunction();">
      <option>--select a party--</option>
        <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["Id"];?>"> 
            <?php echo $row["PartyName"];?>
        </option>
        <?php }}?>  
    </select>
    <div id="showhide"></div>   
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function partyFunction(){
    debugger;
     $("#showhide").empty();
     $("#showhide").html('');
     $("#showhide").append("<table class='table table-bordered text-center table-responsive' border='1px' id='example'>"+
        "<tr>"+  
        "<th>PartyMemberName</th>"+
        "<th>Image</th>"+
        "<th>Info</th>"+
        "</tr>"+
        "<tbody id='partyBody'>"+
         "</tbody>"+
        "</table>"
        );
    $postdata = {};
    $postdata["Id"]=$("#partydropdown").val();
    console.log($("#partydropdown").val());
    $.post('test_data.php',$postdata,function (data) {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data["data"][0].candiateName);
     $("#partyBody").empty();
     $("#partyBody").html('');
     console.log(data["data"]);
     console.log(data["data"].length);
      for(var i=0; i<data["data"].length; i++){
      if(data["data"][i].candiateName != null){ 
      $("#partyBody").append("<tr>"+
              "<td id='resdata"+i+"'></td>"+
              "<td id='resdata1"+i+"' ></td>"+
              "<td id='resdata2"+i+"'></td>"+             
          "</tr>");
           $("#resdata"+i).text(data["data"][i].candiateName);
          $("#resdata1"+i).append("<img id='photo"+i+"'>");
          $("#resdata2"+i).text(data["data"][i].Background);         
          $("#photo"+i).attr('src', 'http://aptsvotes.com/wp-content/themes/apts2019/img'+data["data"][i].Photo );        
        }
    }
    });
    };
    </script>
```

here is the test_data.php code

```
  <?php
    include_once "conn.php";
    include_once "voterdbclass.php";
    session_start();
    $tbl_name2="Parties";
    $dbObj = new Database1();
    $values1 = array("all");
    $querys = "SELECT c1.CandidateName,c1.Photo,c1.Background ,c1.Type FROM aptsv1_votes.Parties p1 LEFT JOIN aptsv1_votes.Candidates c1 ON c1.CurrentPartyId = p1.Id where p1.Id ='" . $_POST['Id'] . "' limit 21";
    $res = $dbObj->SelectRecord($tbl_name2,$values1,"","$querys");
    $data=array();
    $i=0;
    while ($rs = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
      $data[$i]['candiateName']=$rs['CandidateName'];
      $data[$i]['Photo']=$rs['Photo'];
      $data[$i]['Background']=$rs['Background'];
      $i++;
    }
    $json_array= array(
    "data" =>$data
    );
    echo json_encode($json_array);
    ?>
```

Comment: can you show us the raw JSON please? (You can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` just before `$("#partyBody").empty();` in your JS to achieve it...or just look in the response to the AJAX request inside your Network tools and paste it from there)

Comment: P.S small point - you don't need `$("#partyBody").empty();` _and_
     `$("#partyBody").html('');` - in this case they both do the same job.

Comment: Also a warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. You should sort this out immediately after you fix the bug in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i<data["data"].length; i++){
      if(data["data"][i].candiateName != null){ 
          var imge = data["data"][i].Photo;
          var name = data["data"][i].candiateName;
          var bg = data["data"][i].Background;
      $("#partyBody").append("<tr>"+
          "<td id='resdata" + i + "'>" + name+"</td>"+
          "<td id='resdata1" + i + "' ><img id= 'photo" + i + "' src='http://aptsvotes.com/wp-content/themes/apts2019/img'" + imge+"></td>"+
          "<td id='resdata2" + i + "'>" + bg+"</td>"+             
          "</tr>");

        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be better to add some explanation to your answer. What have you changed, and why does it resolve the issue? Otherwise it's harder for people to learn from your answer (rather than just blindly pasting it and hoping, and not being able to understand and re-use the same concepts in future)

Comment: There is a lot of data to display, so i want to display that data in datatables, but datatables are not working..Can you please tell me how to use datatable for above code?

Comment: You can use for datatable jquery see this link for reference. https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse JSON data into the first script. While ajax result you posting with `json_encode`, I found missing

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(data["data"].length);
```

into code

```
$.post('test_data.php',$postdata,function (data) {
 // debugger;
console.log(data);
var data = $.parseJSON(data);  // Add this line in your code and verify
console.log(data["data"].length);
```

Thank you!